# How can i retrieve query params from get request

Tags: ruby, faraday

I'm kind of new to `Ruby` and I stuck with a fairly simple task.
I would like to pass GET parameters to Faraday's request.
Here is my request function

```
def request
  @request ||= Faraday.new do |conn|
  conn.url_prefix = BASE_URL
  conn.headers = @@headers
  conn.request :json
  conn.response :json, parser_options: { object_class: OpenStruct }
end
```

Then this request method is being called like so

```
params = {"date_to": "2021.07.07", "date_from": "2022.01.30"}
request.get(url, params).body
```

I've tried to retrieve params in the request method using `conn.params = @request.params`
But that didn' work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to use `params` in the `request` method then you have to apss it to the method like this:

```
def request(params)
  @request ||= Faraday.new do |conn|
    conn.url_prefix = BASE_URL
    conn.headers = @@headers
    conn.params = params
    conn.request :json
    conn.response :json, parser_options: { object_class: OpenStruct }
end
```

And then call the methods like this:

```
params = { "date_to": "2021.07.07", "date_from": "2022.01.30" }
request(params).get(url).body
```

Comment: oh god so easy, i was passing params to get instead of request :( 
Thank you!